# signout out of twitter using Twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Hi:
Is there anyway my SignoutServlet can sign out of Twitter too ?

I am using something like this

```
    public void doGet(HTTPServletReq req, HTTPServletRes res) throws TwitterException,ServletException
{
   request.getSession(false).invalidate();

}
```

My question is even when I am invalidating the session, my application doesnt log out of Twitter.

Any clues/ideas of how to log out of Twitter from Twitter4j?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like there isnt any solution at this point of time

Answer (score 0):

for signout to twitter just delete the credentials.
means delete the access token simple.